# Is there a way to get around the 500 character limit when coercing expressions to characters using as.character?

Tags: r, expression, character, maxlength

I am currently writing a small package that is supposed to fit multinomial processing tree models (for *not needed* background info a [web page](http://www.uark.edu/misc/lampinen/tutorials/multinomial.htm) and a [pdf](http://psy2.ucsd.edu/~dhuber/math_readings/riefer_batchelder_1988.pdf)).

What it does is the following: It reads a model (i.e., formulas) from a file and converts them (via `parse`) to expressions. Later, some of the variables in these expressions are exchanged by other variables from another file (i.e., model restrictions are applied). Therefore, the model is back transformed to characters (via `as.character`) and the exchange is done via `gsub`.
The problem: If a single expression is longer than 500 characters, transforming them back via `as.character` truncates them to 500 characters (or so).
`?as.character` gives:

> as.character truncates components of
>   language objects to 500 characters
>   (was about 70 before 1.3.1).

Here an example:

```
text1 <- paste(rep(LETTERS, 10), collapse = " + ")
nchar(text1)
[1] 1037

expr1 <- parse(text = text1)
text2 <- as.character(expr1)
[1] 504
```

The question: **Can you get around this 500 character limitation?**

I know we could get around this problem if we would apply the restrictions (i.e., exchange the variables) before we parse the model the first time. But, this would involve a lot of programming, as the whole thing is basically ready, and it would be great if we could get around this 500 character limitations another way.

Comment: Can anyone give a good reason why such a limit would exist in a modern program?

Comment: @David This, is what I thought, too. Especially, why is it hardcoded, and not, for example, changeable in the options??

Comment: That smacks of there being a statically sized array, `char s[500]` which seems lame. Perhaps there's a good reason....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, by doing ugly things with deparse and gsub:

```
expr1 <- parse(text = text1)
attributes(expr1) <- NULL
(text3 <- paste(deparse(expr1), collapse=""))
#rm whitespace etc
(text3 <- gsub("\\)$", "", gsub("^expression\\(", "", 
        gsub("[[:space:]][[:space:]]+", " ", text3))))
nchar(text3)
```

More to the point of your application, you can use `deparse` to make strings out of formulas,
and use this function:

```
safeDeparse <- function(expr){
    ret <- paste(deparse(expr), collapse="")
    #rm whitespace
    gsub("[[:space:]][[:space:]]+", " ", ret)
}
```

to get around the stupid length limit that makes deparse add linebreaks and split a single expression into many strings, compare:

```
(f <- formula(paste("X ~", paste(rep(letters, 10), collapse=" + "))))
deparse(f)
safeDeparse(f)
```

Comment: That sounds interesting. I tried to play around with `deparse`, too. But got a `contextstack overflow at line 2`. But I will try your version immediately.

Comment: This code works on my machine, too. But there is an issue in my **real** program that still produces this error. But, I am on my way of finding it...

Comment: Ahh, I forgot to get rid of the `expression(` after deparsing. Now everything works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

From Base Version 2.15.0 the as.character now has this behaviour

> as.character breaks lines in language objects at 500 characters, and inserts newlines.

To get the package version use:

```
packageVersion("base")
```

Cheers